# How to achieve Dynamic forms with `HTML <input> placeholder Attribute` in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, dynamic-forms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. How to use `HTML <input> placeholder Attribute` instead of labels in `dynamic forms` module?

Comment: Extremely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question, I made an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shape tracing feature from the designer tools module to find the right shapes to override, and what alternate templates to write. Most likely, you'll find that you need to override the `Elements_TextField` shape and replace:

```
@if (element.ShowLabel) {
    <label for="@element.HtmlId">@Model.ProcessedLabel</label>
}
```

with:

```
@if (element.ShowLabel) {
    tagBuilder.Attributes["placeholder"] = Model.ProcessedLabel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried to use shape tracing but couldn't find this shape "Elements_TextField", in my shape tree the leaves were Shape "Element" and Shape "ElementZone". So I create a "Elements_TextField.cshtml" file in CurrentTheme/Views folder and copy the content of Orchard.DynamicForms/Views/Elements/TextField.cshtml, inside this file and made the replace that you mentioned and it worked.